# Ways to include inline SVG many times in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

If you could recommend some good complex article about ways of multiple including inline SVG images? Possibly without using server-side.

Or maybe this topic would be a good place to gather best solutions?
The key is to keep same SVG data inline (for easier manipulation on styles) and use it many times on website.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank you, that's why I added that maybe this topic would be the best place to list a solutions for multiple include of SVGs :)

Comment: The question is too broad for that. Have you considered the `use` element?

Answer (score -1):

There are many JS libraries available, you can use any of them. Couple of examples:

http://svgjs.dev/

http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: Thank you! Those libraries are great of course but they are too complex -- focused on animations. What I'd like to achieve is the best method for simple and effective multiply inclusions of SVG code.